# Formatting results in MySQL issue

Tags: mysql

I am using the

`FORMAT(SUM(columnName),3)`

to format my result. I got this result for instance: `1,746,677.360`  . I need to replace the "," with "." and the "." with "," so finally I should get this format:`1.746.677,360` . How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `REPLACE` function of mysql

```
REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)
```

Comment: from mysql 5.5 and up the format function works a lot better, i'd suggest using `FORMAT(string, 3, 'de_DE')` as that is a lot more readable and elegant. 'de_DE' corresponds to a locale which uses this number format, which is why that one was picked.